# How to exit a qemu monitor telnet session beautifully?

Tags: qemu

In a telnet session of the qemu monitor, the exit command doesn't exit the command session. It exits the emulator, i.e. the emulated virtual machine gets a hard poweroff.

I use the qemu monitor from simply telnetting to its port. I would like to leave this session on a better way than breaking the tcp connection.

Is there a way to exit the monitor beautifully?

Comment: Put another way, you want a monitor command which instructs QEMU to close the connection, instead of using Ctrl+] on the client side, is that right?

Comment: @StephenKitt Exactly. The usual behavior of any remote control is that they have a better option to disconnect than ctrl+].

Comment: @StephenKitt (side note: qemu VMs are running by me in headless mode as systemd services, bridged to the main eth :-). I connect them with vnc (supported by the qemu), or the usual remote control functionality of the guest OSes (rdesktop/ssh) ). In general I found qemu very effective and flexible, real linuxish way. But... honestly, this monitor thing doesn't seem very well developed. More exactly, I think it is totally crap. I think I would need a hardware tree, and into this tree should be attachable/configurable the different devices. I think I will have some question about it later.